# Get Objective Function values in each iteration while using lmfit.minimize

Tags: python, minimize, lmfit

I am trying to use lmfit.minimize to minimize an objective function (which is a sum of squared error). I can use `lmfit.minimize(function,params,args)`   to do it and it returns a Minimizer object with fit statistics. However, I want to see how the objective function value changes in each iteration.
I could print values in each iteration or plot individual residual values using an iteration callback function but I want to get the values of objective function as an array that I can later use/plot.
How can it be done  ?

I am trying to get something like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this functionality exists in lmfit. If not, what you could do, is, inside the objective function, to append the value to a list. The list could be a global variable or an instance variable (if you set the objective function to be an instance method). If you want a live update, you could send this value over a queue to another thread that does updates a plot (but you mention "later use/plot", so that's probably not necessary).

Comment: (cont.) Note that for one of these methods, you might be able to make use of a [callback function](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html#using-a-iteration-callback-function).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @9769953, thank you for the input. After trying several things, using a global variable to track the objective function and reset it after every use was the best thing I could do. I was trying to see if I can avoid that but with lmfit.minimize, apparently, I can't.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you have to reset it after every use. But see my answer for a suggestion how to use the iterative callback function to store the residual value for each iteration. You can adopt that to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do with the iterative callback function (using the example from the lmfit homepage):

```
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters
import numpy as np

def myfunc(x, amp, phase, freq, decay):
    return amp * np.sin(x*freq + phase) * np.exp(-x*x*decay)

def residual(params, x, data, uncertainty, *args, **kws):
    """Model a decaying sine wave and subtract data."""

    model = myfunc(x, params['amp'], params['phase'], params['freq'], params['decay'])

    return (data-model) / uncertainty

x = np.linspace(0, 100)
noise = np.random.normal(size=x.size, scale=0.2)
data = myfunc(x, 7.5, 2.5, 0.22, 0.01) + noise

# generate experimental uncertainties
uncertainty = np.abs(0.16 + np.random.normal(size=x.size, scale=0.05))

def callback(params, iter, resid, *args, **kws):
    itervalues = kws['itervalues']
    itervalues.append((resid**2).sum())

params = Parameters()
params.add('amp', value=10)
params.add('decay', value=0.007)
params.add('phase', value=0.2)
params.add('freq', value=3.0)

itervalues = []
result = minimize(residual, params, args=(x, data, uncertainty), iter_cb=callback, kws={'itervalues': itervalues})
```

and `itervalues` will have the values you're looking for, in progressive order. (There's often a high number at the start, when the algorithm is trying out different directions.)

This uses the mutability of Python lists, since that's the only way `callback` can change `itervalues`; its return value is used for something different, so that can't be used to change `itervalues`.